# Instalation Manager 1.6.2 Unable to load the package

Tags: websphere, ibm-installation-manager

When Launching the Install.exe , I am getting the following error:

[image]

The Install XML file has the following values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<agent-input clean='true' temporary='true'>

<server>

 <repository location='.'/>

<repository location='http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V85WASDeveloperILANL'/>

</server>

<install>

 <offering features='agent_core,agent_jre' id='com.ibm.cic.agent' version='1.6.2000.20130301_2248' />

  <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85' />

  <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.IBMJAVA.v70' selected='false' />

  <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.liberty.IBMJAVA.v70' selected='false' />

 <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.IHSILAN.v85' selected='false' />

 <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.APPCLIENTILAN.v85' selected='false' />

  <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.PLGILAN.v85' selected='false' />

  <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.PLUGCLIENTILAN.v85' selected='false' />

  <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.WCTILAN.v85' selected='false' />

 <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.W2MTKILAN.v11' selected='false' />

 <offering id='com.ibm.websphere.liberty.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85' selected='false' />

</install>

</agent-input>
```

Comment: Check if you have Internet connection and if firewall is not blocking IManger. I have same effect, if I run it without network.

Comment: @Gas, I had disabled Firewall and Internet is working fine. I have set the proxy on my Internet Explorer and all sites are working just fine . Any other configuration I need to look in?

Comment: If you are using proxy to connect to Internet you may try solution from [this link](http://sys101.doloveyou.com/year/2014/articles/use_ibm_installation_manager_behind_firewall_or_proxy.html) or just download locally package you want to install.

Comment: @Gas, Tried but this is also not working

Comment: Try to download the latest version from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/) it is using IM 1.8 and looks like it is working.

Comment: @Gas, Same issue with 1.8 too. Is this because I set proxy URL http://mydomain/setpac.pac , ending with pac file

Comment: I have direct connection (no proxy) and it works fine. You should put a hostname there, not a pac file.